# Make a kibana chart field clickable + popup

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I currently have this Kibana chart
[image]

I would like to make it so that when I click on a path it opens up a popup to my local PC accessing the image in the path.
As I am a new user I am stuck on how to proceed with this, any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-data-views.html#string-field-formatters, where you use a url formatter and then it would start with `file://`, then add your local path

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I followed the instruction by setting format to URL, type to Image, and URL template to file://{{value}}.
I am now getting image icon that are not showing with text : A dynamically-specified image located at file://C%3A%5Cimage_data%5Cimages%5Caudi.png